# Windows 7 Reliability Monitor

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Is it possible to reset Reliability Monitor to a zero state, thus obtaining a clean slate?

I also find it is slow to open on my system and sometimes becomes unresponsive. Any ideas how to improve that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggetsion for Vista - maybe of some use: http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/174035-reliability-monitor-reset.html

slothistype